# 2 identical executors with identical data volumes performing 10x-30x slower/faster than each other

Tags: apache-spark

#### Problem

I have a stage I'm analyzing that's taking several minutes, and it's representative of multiple stages in my application with this duration that are wasting a lot of overall time. My goal is to optimize this duration.

#### Description

The task time distribution looks like this:

[image]

This would appear like data skew; however, check these metrics:

[image]

The executors I'm interested in are 2 and 4. Notice they have the same read/write volumes. In fact, 2 has slightly more.

But their durations couldn't be more different:

[image]

##### Other details

Both executors ran node_local.

The workers are google cloud (gke) provisioned, and have the same node types (8 cores / 64 Gb RAM) and executor configuration, so the executors and infrastructure are identically setup.

#### Question

If I rule out data skew, locality, and infrastructural or configuration differences, what else could be the reason for 1 executor performing so drastically differently from a neighboring executor?

To be honest, I'm just not sure I understand why sometimes shuffle reads/writes can take longer for some executors than others in the same stage, given the same locality and setup.

PS: The DAG for reference:

[image]

Here's the rest of the executor tasks from screenshot 3, if it's of any help:

[image]

**Spark 3.2.0**

Comment: Interesting question! Can you share which code results in this query plan?

Comment: @Koedlt Unfortunately, I am somewhat limited in that respect as it's proprietary, and I don't have free access to the full code. The code is in Spark SQL. I did snip the relevant sql based on where the stage was active in the DAG from the spark ui and SQL tab. Here's a link: https://pastebin.pl/view/e385a86b Apologies in advance if it's annoyingly obfuscated. I marked the lines where this stage appears in exchange nodes of the DAG (marked via text "relevant to stage")

Comment: Oh damn I'm afraid that with limited info like this I can't really figure this one out... Try to understand exactly which computations make up your DAG and how a similar amount of data can end up in way more intensive calculations (not very helpful, I know haha)

Comment: @Koedlt I completely understand. I kinda knew it was a long shot asking a question while handcuffing people on the information. Assuming I did have suspicions on the query, is there anything i could do to help the driver distribute the data better, for example in the case that the most hotspotted join keys are being allocated to 1 executor? Could something like ColumnStat or NoScan stats play a role in how join columns are partitioned / distributed? I already gather basic statistics. Or is this a completely unrelated direction?

Comment: Although then again, the issue is in shuffle write time and not exec time, so maybe this is the right line of thought.